# Regex for Delimeter

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write a regex for delimiters `“(“, “)”, “,”`. I tried to write a regex but it is not the correct for the delimeters.

Let's say the input is `mult(3,add(2,subs(4,3)))`. The output with my delimeter regex is: `3,add(2,subs(4,3`.

```
public class Practice {

    private static final String DELIMETER = "\\((.*?)\\)";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        String arg = reader.next();
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(DELIMETER);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(arg);
        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group(1));
        }
    }
}
```

What is the correct regex to get string between the delimeters?

Comment: You cannot match nested brackets in Java regex.

Comment: What should I do then?

Comment: It seems to me that you want the match to be greedy, not reluctant.  What happens if you remove the `?` from the middle of the expression?

Comment: How do you want to split `"mult(3,add(2,subs(4,3)))"`?

Answer (score 0):

In general, you cannot use a regex to match anything which can nest recursively. However, if you removed the `?` from your regex, it would match from the first `(` to the last `)`, which might be good enough, depending on what you expect the input to look like.